# Discord.js how to make the bot being mentioned a prefix

Tags: discord

I tried making it "prefix" : "<@BOTID>" but that didnt work so i figured i would ask somebody here my bot has a seperate file with the prefix and token and stuff so heres the code thats in it minus the bot token

```
{
    "token": "BOTTOKEN",
    "prefix": "<@542949851617296416>"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside the `client.On('message'...`:

```js
client.On('message', msg => {
   if msg.content.startsWith(prefix) == true {
      var cmd = msg.content.split(prefix.length + 1);
      // Handle command via cmd variable
   };
});
```

Be careful, though. The +1 is there because Discord puts a space after a mention. This can be removed and have it still work by putting a space after the mention in the config. Like so: `"<@...> "`, instead of `"<@...>"`.

To use an external file for your bot configuration, then you must `require` it. How to use these variables are also shown with an example below.

```js
const {token,prefix} = require('./configFileName.json');

client.login(prefix);
```